# How do I know what Steam is downloading?

Tags: steam

It has been downloading something at full bandwidth for some time now. And it is just about 50% completed. But nothing is showing on the download tab. So, what is it downloading?

Comment: I think if you hover over the Steam icon it will say what it is downloading.

Comment: It stopped after restart, wired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cant see it in Downloads on the client, then I normally go to Steam folder, then Steamapps/Common and sort the folders by "Date modified".